# Implementing a Client using Mongoose with C++

Tags: c++, mongoose-web-server

I know how to implement a server with Mongoose, in fact all information that I could find was about servers, but I need to know how do I implement a client.

Very basic, how to connect to a server is the main problem, the send functions are pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose is a web server and AFAIK does not provide an API for client side http requests.

For C++ http client libraries, you might want to look at these answers:

- [What C++ library should I use to implement a HTTP client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822581/what-c-library-should-i-use-to-implement-a-http-client)
- [A better C++ HTTP client library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816102/a-better-c-http-client-library)

These sites also give a good overview about available C++ client libraries:

- http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late reply, I was trying to avoid adding more libraries, I figured out that I could live just sending responses (thus not requiring client code).

But I'll keep your suggestions for when I need an http client, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose actually does provide HTTP client functionality. See `mg_connect()` on http://cesanta.com/docs/API.shtml. Also, example HTTP client code is at https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/tree/master/examples/http_client

I suggest using Fossa library (a superset of Mongoose), as it's HTTP client interface is more flexible. Example code is at https://github.com/cesanta/fossa/tree/master/examples/restful_client , documentation is at http://cesanta.com/docs/fossa/

Comment: Alas, it appears as though Fossa development has stopped about the same time as you wrote this. For the past few years, only Mongoose has been improved.

Comment: Yeah, cause Fossa became Mongoose.